# How do I refactor two methods with very similar list types into a generic method?

Tags: c#, function, generics, methods, refactoring

I have two methods which are very similar. The only difference is the type used in the `BindingList`, but I can't work out how to create a generic method for both types. I think I have to use generic types  to get it to work, but I can't figure it out. Both the types have a `Title` property.

```
private int GetObjectIndexFromTitle(string str, BindingList<MyClass1> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Title == str)
        {
            return list.IndexOf(item);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And this:

```
private int GetObjectIndexFromTitle(string str, BindingList<MyClass2> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Title == str)
        {
            return list.IndexOf(item);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I've looked through the Generic Type documentation, but I couldn't get it to work because of the very specific `Title` property. I would love some help with this.

Comment: If they both have a `Title` property then this would be a good case for a common interface such as `IHasTitle`.

Answer (score 4):

Create an interface with:

```
public interface ITitleAware{
   string Title { get; } 
}
```

Your classes will implement it:

```
public MyClass1 : ITitleAware {
   //code
}

public MyClass2 : ITitleAware {
   //code
}
```

Then:

```
private int GetObjectIndexFromTitle(string str, BindingList<ITitleAware> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Title == str)
        {
            return list.IndexOf(item);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So my usual code for the classes goes in `//code`, right?

Comment: @n00dles Yes. Make sure those classes have a Title otherwise the code won't compile.

Comment: When I call `GetObjectIndexFromTitle("string", MyBindingListClass1)`, it give me a second argument error. `BindingList<myClass1> cannot be converted to BindingList<ITitleAware>` ...

Comment: @n00dles Why is it "myClass1" instead of "MyClass1"? Regardless, it seems you forgot to add the interface to your class, i.e. adding ": ITitleAware".

Comment: I created the interface(`...Add Item > Interface`) and added what you posted into it. I also implemented it with the `: ITitleAware` bits. I'll post all the relevant code if you'd like.

Answer (score -2):

```
   public static class myClass
    {
        public static int GetObjectIndexFromTitle<T>(T myList, string myString)
        {
            foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                if (item.Title == myString)
                {
                    return list.IndexOf(item);
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
myClass.GetObjectIndexFromTitle<myClass1>(myList1, "myString1");
myClass.GetObjectIndexFromTitle<myClass222>(myList2222, "myString222");
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Kyle Did you define myClass1 and myClass222. I assume not. Code fragment meant to be a benchmark to point in the right direction.

Comment: No, because your implementation of `GetObjectIndexFromTitle` doesn't need or depend on them.  Your method implementation won't work because without constraints, there will be a compile error when trying to use `myList` in a `foreach` loop (since there's nothing guaranteeing that `T` is enumerable) and, even fixing that, there's no constraint which guarantees that `item` has a `Title` property.